# service xend start hangs after server crash / reboot

Tags: xen

Folks,

I've had a CENTOS box running two xen VMs for a couple of years. Yesterday the ISP had a heat problem and the server went down. Now the host OS on the box is back up but I can't restart the XEND service. I do the 'service xend start' and the only output I see in the log file is:

```
    [2010-11-08 08:25:57 xend 2970] INFO (SrvDaemon:283) Xend Daemon started
[2010-11-08 08:25:57 xend 2970] INFO (SrvDaemon:287) Xend changeset: unavailable .
[2010-11-08 08:25:57 xend 2970] ERROR (SrvDaemon:297) Exception starting xend ((111, 'Connection refused'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/server/SrvDaemon.py", line 291, in run
    servers = SrvServer.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/server/SrvServer.py", line 108, in create
    root.putChild('xend', SrvRoot())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/server/SrvRoot.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/web/SrvDir.py", line 82, in get
    val = val.getobj()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/web/SrvDir.py", line 52, in getobj
    self.obj = klassobj()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/server/SrvDomainDir.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.xd = XendDomain.instance()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/XendDomain.py", line 655, in instance
    inst.init()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/XendDomain.py", line 71, in init
    xstransact.Mkdir(VMROOT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/xenstore/xstransact.py", line 345, in Mkdir
    complete(path, lambda t: t.mkdir(*args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/xenstore/xstransact.py", line 351, in complete
    t = xstransact(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/xenstore/xstransact.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.transaction = xshandle().transaction_start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/xen/xend/xenstore/xsutil.py", line 18, in xshandle
    xs_handle = xen.lowlevel.xs.xs()
Error: (111, 'Connection refused')
~
```

When I Ctrl+c the start command I see this trace which makes it look like maybe the issue is with xenstored?:

```
Starting xend: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/xend", line 134, in ?
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/sbin/xend", line 111, in main
    start_xenstored()
  File "/usr/sbin/xend", line 90, in start_xenstored
    s,o = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/commands.py", line 54, in getstatusoutput
    text = pipe.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What versions are you on?

Comment: rpm shows:rpm -qa | grep xen 
kernel-xen-2.6.18-8.1.15.el5
xen-libs-3.0.3-25.0.4.el5
xen-3.0.3-25.0.4.el5

Comment: Some more information, the xenstored process is taking 100% of the CPU and apparently not completing. It's been running for 17 minutes now and counting. I'm going to try just leaving it but it seems likely it's just stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it is of use to future generations. The issue appeared to be a corrupt install of the Xen libraries. Likely when the server crashed they got subtly munged. Doing an upgrade using a new RPM solved the problem. The existing VM images could then be started and used unchanged.